# Searchbox in grid error message as a result of Xcode 9 upgrade

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xcode9

I use visual studio for Mac to develop my Xamarin forms application and set it to download the stable updates regularly. I got a message to upgrade my Xcode to version 9 and I did. 
I have a search box in a grid in my app and this has not been able to work again. All I got is the error message below. Any ideas how I can fix this? If I comment out the search box it works but I need it.

> Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException
>   Reason: -[UISearchBar sizeThatFits:] does not support passing
>   non-finite values ({inf, 56}) Native stack trace:     0   CoreFoundation 
>   0x0000000103a971cb __exceptionPreprocess + 171    1   libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x000000011115df41 objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000103a9c362 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98    3
>   Foundation                          0x00000001046c2089
>   -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193     4
>   UIKit                               0x0000000107e9802b -[UISearchBar
>   sizeThatFits:] + 347  5   Articles.iOS
>   0x00000001033f8f49 xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend + 217     6   ???
>   0x000000013198ff40 0x0 + 5127077696   7   ???
>   0x00000001319847a2 0x0 + 5127030690

Comment: For people who will like to know, I resolved this by defining a width for the search box such as widrequest="30" and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/103579/search-bar-crash-on-new-version-of-xamarin-with-latest-xcode).

1. Create a custom renderer in iOS for SearchBar
2. **Override** SizeThatFits method
3. return some default size

```cs
        using System;
        using PROJ.iOS.Renders;
        using Xamarin.Forms;
        using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

        [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(SearchBar), typeof(CustomSearchbarRenderer))]
        namespace PROJ.iOS.Renders
        {
            public class CustomSearchbarRenderer : SearchBarRenderer
            {
                public CustomSearchbarRenderer()
                {
                }
                public override CoreGraphics.CGSize SizeThatFits(CoreGraphics.CGSize size)
                {
                    return new CoreGraphics.CGSize(30, 30);
                }
            }
        }
```